# Resque status update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-4, resque

In a rails4 app I have a very long task (can take hours) handled by resque (like railscasts #271).

The create action in the controller looks like this:

```
  def create
    @longstuff = Longstuff.new(params[:longstuff])
    if @longstuff.save
      Resque.enqueue(LongStuffHandler, @longstuff.id)
      redirect_to @longstuff, :notice => "Success."
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I want to update the user on the status of the queue and give him useful information (stats, elapsed time, progressbars etc.)

My idea is to create a div in the "new" view that autorefreshes with javascript every 3 seconds and displays some content that the LongStuffHandler class provides.

So far I've been able to achieve that making the LongStuffHandler class write some html to a file that is loaded by the javascript.
This leads to several problems, for example writing to a file 10 times per second is less than ideal.

I would like to have the LongStuffHandler class to be able to export some variables in real time and making them available to the "new" view so that just reloading a partial will make my page look updated.
An example would be that the LongStuffHandler class has a variable called "@lastlog" and makes it available to the "new" view where there is a div like this autoupdated by javascript:

```
<div class="lastlog">
  <h2>Last Log</h2>
  <p><%= @lastlog %></p>
</div>
```

Is it possible for the background job to export such a variable and for the view to import  it?